# What's the shortcut for hiding / showing the 3D cursor?

Tags: 3d-cursor

After reading the long list of shortcuts in blender I don't see it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't one.  You need to toggle a setting in *Viewport Overlays*.

But you can create one, or add a Quick Menu entry.

The 3D Cursor is an *overlay*  If you open the overlay menu in the 3D Viewport header you can find that it has a checkbox.

[image: Overlay menu showing 3D cursor]

If you right click while you are hovering over it, a popup menu appears that allows you to set the shortcut:

[image: Popup menu for setting short cut]

or you can add it to your quick favorite menu if you don't want to tie a key sequence to it.  The short cut for bringing up the *Quick Favorite* popup menu is <kbd>Q</kbd>  Here's mine with only *Show 3D Cursor* as an entry

[image: Quick favorites menu]

*Note:*  If you assign a shortcut key that is already assigned, Blender will quietly make the assignment, but the existing assignment will override and your shortcut won't work.  This is why I use the quick menu for things like this.